# Ruby on rails form variables as array items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, form-helpers

I have a simple form with text input and text area, but when I submit it the variables seems to be array items instead of just string values?

**the form**

```
<%= form_tag(home_kontak_path, :remote => true) do %>
<label>Jou epos adres</label>
<%= text_field(:epos, "", :placeholder => "Jou epos adres", :id => "epos", :class => "input-block-level") %>

<label>Boodskap hier</label>
<%= text_area(:boodskap, "", :rows => "5", :placeholder => "Boodskap hier...", :id => "boodskap", :class => "input-block-level") %>

<%= submit_tag "submit" %>
<% end %>
```

**console output**

```
Started POST "/home/kontak" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-23 11:53:03 +0200
Processing by HomeController#kontak as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i+5UWaQeBu7LYGPFBNAbum+67VzyyC82JN2wMlLc/UU=", "epos"=>["text box value"], "boodskap"=>["text area value"], "commit"=>""}
```

**what i would like it to be**
instead of

> "epos"=>["text box value"]

i want it to return

> "epos"=>"text box value"

**Update**
I have tried the following syntax to no avail

```
<%= text_field "epos", "", :placeholder => "Jou epos adres", :id => "epos", :class => "input-block-level" %>
```

and

```
<%= text_field :epos, "", :placeholder => "Jou epos adres", :id => "epos", :class => "input-block-level" %>
```

i still get

```
Started POST "/home/kontak" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-23 13:34:57 +0200
Processing by HomeController#kontak as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"i+5UWaQeBu7LYGPFBNAbum+67VzyyC82JN2wMlLc/UU=", "epos"=>["asd"], "boodskap"=>["asd"], "commit"=>""}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this format instead of the above one.

```
<%= text_field_tag :epos, "", :placeholder => "Jou epos adres", :id => "epos", :class => "input-block-level" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found my own problem :)

I replaced **text_field** with **text_field_tag** and **text_area** with **text_area_tag**

now it shows the correct output as sting items and not array items

```
Parameters: {"epos"=>"epos adr here", "boodskap"=>"boodskap here"}
```